# How to blog on website without changing html code

Tags: html, css, web, blogs

I have nearly setup a blog using html and css and I am about to set up the individual blog pages. But it seems a bit tedious to me that I will have to edit the html code for the blog pages everytime I make a new page. Is there a way around this? I want to be able to simply write my new blog post on any text editor and not have to fiddle around with the code and see it on the website.

Edit: I do not want to use applications like tumblr for my site. I would prefer if there was simple dialogue box where I could write my post and see it updated to the website.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use [Tumblr](http://tumblr.com).

You can choose template, creating blog posts with few simple clicks, but you can also spice up your layout with minor HTML and CSS changes if you want to - of course you can always go back to default template.

Comment: not in the mood of using tumblr. I want to make it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand is that you don't use a system to write blog posts but just bare HTML and CSS. That can be of course tedious and dreadful boring.

What you could do that comes closest to your needs is using something like [jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) which takes your content and combines it with your template.

This is just one blog system/CMS. There are hundreds and thousands out there (like Wordpress, Drupal, Joomla, Ghost, ...).

Keep in mind, that all solutions come with some extra tools to work with. Jekyll for example runs with ruby and needs to compile your blog each time you edit/add/remove something - it still is kind of the simplest and safest system (in my opinion) to run a blog. You don't have to know any ruby to run it. It just needs ruby to compile your content.

Comment: But you need to remember that Jekyll needs Ruby and compilation - but I can recommend this tool

Comment: I am not in the mood of learning ruby and I purposefully walked away from Wordpress as it didn't offer much flexibility. Is there anything else. I know python 3 too so anything with that will be good

Comment: There is no need to learn ruby. Jekyll is super simple. All you need to know is how to run a command in a terminal. I bet there are a lot of python blog systems out there too.